# Expo IntentLauncher can't open Application_Details_Settings

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I want to open the details settings of my application from the app itself.
I use the IntentLauncher from Expo itself: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/intent-launcher

The code I use that I assume should work is:

```
IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(IntentLauncher.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
```

But this gives me this error:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method startActivity on module ExpoIntentLauncher: null]

I'm not sure if I should give some kind of parameter with it so it links to my app?

Opening all other settings does work, ex:

```
IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(IntentLauncher.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS)
```

This does open a list off all apps, I just need to get the detailed screen of the app itself, not the list.

Comment: Same problem here, did you manage to do it ?

Comment: @DonovanBENFOUZARI No, I haven't found a solution to this. Nothing seemed to work and I the only things I found were people saying it's currently not possible. Because this was a minor feature we decided to remove it from the scope. If you by any chance find a solution, let me know. Good luck!

Comment: Want I wanted to do is open the permissions. Since it's not possible for Android, I do it for iOS but I ask for the user to accept the camera permission every time he tries to access it. This solution is not possible on iOS but this workaround is ok.

Answer (score 6):

I found this [solution](https://forums.expo.io/t/opening-device-settings-on-android-using-linking/2059/10) by **bodolsog** working.

Complete solution

```
import * as IntentLauncher from "expo-intent-launcher";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

const pkg = Constants.manifest.releaseChannel
      ? Constants.manifest.android.package  // When published, considered as using standalone build
      : "host.exp.exponent"; // In expo client mode

IntentLauncherAndroid.startActivityAsync(
  IntentLauncherAndroid.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
  { data: 'package:' + pkg },
)
```

Comment: Perhaps due to an update, i was forced to change the last call to use  IntentLauncher.ActivityAction.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps someone

```js
import { startActivityAsync, ActivityAction } from 'expo-intent-launcher';
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const pkg = Constants.manifest.releaseChannel
  ? Constants.manifest.android.package // When published, considered as using standalone build
  : 'host.exp.exponent'; // In expo client mode


openSettings = async () => {
    try {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        // console.log(Constants);
        startActivityAsync(ActivityAction.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, {
          data: 'package:' + pkg,
        });
      }
      if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        Linking.openSettings();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).